# What method is used to find the number of Hamiltonian paths of a fan graph in this proof?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Theorem: The fan graph f_n+2 can be decomposed into 4n+2 Hamiltonian paths.

Proof:
Let f_n+2 be the fan graph with vertex set V: {z,v_1,v_2,..,v_n+1,v_n+2}.
Consider the vertex z. We construct a path P_n+2: v_1,v_2,..,v_n+1,v_n+2 excluding the vertex z. Connect the vertex z to the vertex v_1 of P_n+2, we get a spanning path Q_1:z,v_1,v_2,..,v_n+1,v_n+2. Also, connect the vertex z to the vertex v_n+2 of P_n+2, we get a spanning path Q_2: v_1,v_2,..,v_n+1,v_n+2,z. Therefore, considering the vertex z, we get **2** spanning paths.

Consider the vertex v_1. **We construct n+2** paths excluding the vertex v_1.

R_1: z,v_2,v_3,v_4,..,v_n,v_n+1,v_n+2

R_2: v_2,z,v_3,v_4,..,v_n,v_n+1,v_n+2

R_3: v_2,v_3,z,v_4,..,v_n,v_n+1,v_n+2
.

.

.

R_n: v_2,v_3,v_4,.., v_n,z,v_n+1,v_n+2

R_n+1: v_2,v_3,v_4,.., v_n,v_n+1,z,v_n+2

R_n+2: v_2,v_3,v_4,.., v_n,v_n+1,v_n+2,z

Connect the vertex v_1 to the starting vertex of each paths R_i, 1<= i <= n+2, we get n+2 spanning paths. But the spanning path R’_n+2: v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,..,v_n,v_n+1,v_n+2,z is same as Q_2: v_1,v_2,..,v_n+1,v_n+2,z. So we get **n+1** spanning paths.

Also, **we construct n paths** excluding the vertex v_1.

S_1: z,v_n+2,v_n+1,v_n,..,v_5,v_4,v_3,v_2

S_2: v_2,z,v_n+2,v_n+1,v_n,..,v_5,v_4,v_3

S_3: v_2,v_3,z,v_n+2,v_n+1,v_n,..,v_5,v_4
.

.

.

S_n-2: v_2,v_3,v_4,..,v_n-2,z,v_n+2,v_n+1,v_n,v_n-1

S_n-1: v_2, v_3,v_4,..,v_n-1,z,v_n+2,v_n+1,v_n

S_n: v_2,v_3,v_4,..,v_n-1,z,v_n+2,v_n+1

Connect the vertex v_1 to the starting vertex of each paths S_i, 1<= I <= n, we get n spanning paths. Therefore, considering the vertex v_1, we get **2n+1** spanning paths.

Proceeding like this we get a sequence of Hamiltonian paths, 2,2n+1,**2,2,..,2,1.**
The number of Hamiltonian paths in

f_n+2 = (2+2n+1)+**(2+2+..+2)(n-1)**+1

= 2n+3+2(n-1)+1

= 2n+4+2n-2

= 4n+2

I saw this proof and I understand the idea of the proof. However, I don't know how or where some value came from. At first they constructed n+2 paths resulted to n+1 spanning paths. Next, they constructed n paths resulted to n paths. So n+1 + n = 2n+1, they got 2n+1 spanning paths. Where does the constructed number of paths n+2 and n came from?

And for this sequence of hamiltonian paths 2,2n+1,(2,2,..,2,1). I know that the 2 and 2n+1 came from the number got from the proof. How about the next sequence of number (2,2,..,2,1)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How can the fan graph possibly be decomposed into $4n+2$ Hamiltonian paths? If this is the usual definition of a fan graph, the $n+3$ vertex-graph only has $2n+5$ edges; this is not enough even for $3$ edge-disjoint Hamiltonian paths. Perhaps you are arguing that it *contains* $4n+2$ different Hamiltonian paths?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not surprised you are confused. That description is torturous. Even the way they are counting this seems unnecessarily confusing. Why $n+2$ and not just $n$?

Recall that $f_{n+2}$ is formed by taking a straight path graph $P_{n+2}$, which we can think of as $n+2$ vertices on a straight line, with the edges being the segments between adjacent vertices, and adding a new vertex $z$ off that line, then connecting it to each of the previous vertices. Based on how they describe the paths, I think they originally started doing an inductive proof based on the length of $P_{n+2}$, by removing an endpoint, and figuring out how it could be added back in to the Hamiltonian paths of $f_{n+1}$. But along the way, they realized that describing the new paths made the induction moot. Thus we have this quixotic description of the paths in terms of a removed $v_1$.

The only Hamiltonian path for $P = P_{n+2}$ is the path graph itself. $z$ gives us some alternatives. But we can only visit $z$ once, so at most two of its connecting paths can be traversed. The question becomes how can we adapt $P$ to pick up $z$? If we have a path that visits $z$ at some point then goes back down to $P$, if the path were to go down to a vertex with two unvisited neighbors on $P$, whichever way we left that vertex would cut off ever visiting the other neighbor, meaning the path would not be Hamiltonian. So if we want a Hamiltonian path, either $z$ connects to one or both of the two endpoints, or else it connects to two adjacent vertices of $P$. Which leaves us with four choices on how the path can go:

[image]

- The first choice is simply to connect $z$ to one of the endpoints of $P$ and call it done. Since there are two endpoints, there are two such paths. They call these $Q_1$ and $Q_2$. These are the only Hamiltonian paths to have $z$ as one of the endpoints.
- Second, we can start at $v_1$, travel right along $P$ to some $v_k, 1 \le k \le n+1$, then pop up to $z$, and back down to $v_{k+1}$, where the path continues along $P$ to $v_{n+2}$. These are the paths they call $R_k'$. Since there are $n+1$ choices for $k$, this gives $n+1$ paths.
- Third, we can start at $v_1$, proceed right to $v_k$, up to $z$, then back down to the other endpoint $v_{n+2}$, and follow the path left to end at $v_{k+1}$. If we allow $k = n+1$, then coming back down to $v_{n+2}$, there would no place to go, which would result in the same path as in the previous case. So this time we have to restrict $1 \le k \le n$, giving $n$ paths starting at $v_1$. On the other hand, this option treats $v_1$ and $v_{n+2}$ in different manners. So you get a different path if you reversed it, starting at $v_{n+2}$, travelling left to $v_{k+1}$, popping up to $z$, back down to $v_1$, then heading right to end at $v_k$. So this contributes $2n$ total Hamilton paths. This appears to be their paths $S_k$. Though I have no clue at all how they came up with a count of "$2n+1$".
- Finally, we can start at some $v_k, 2 \le k \le n$, travel left to $v_1$, up to $z$, back down to $v_{n+2}$ and left again to $v_{k+1}$. If $k = 1$ or $n+1$, this would repeat a path of the previous case, so those are excluded. There are $n-1$ possible paths. I don't see where this fits in their descriptions. I suppose that incomprehensible thing beginning with "Proceeding like this" was intended to count them. But if I were an educator grading this proof, I would have given it a failing grade.

Adding it all together we have $2+ n+1 + 2n + n-1 = 4n+2$ possible Hamilton paths in total.

Comment: An easier approach to counting the Hamilton paths occurs to me: you could add a path from $v_1$ to $v_{n+2}$, so adding $z$ forms a wheel graph. In that wheel graph, a hamiltonian path having $z$ as an endpoint will drop to the wheel somewhere and go around until just shy of where it first landed, leaving a single gap. A hamiltonian path having $z$ in the middle will drop from $z$ to two vertices, and head around untill it cannot, leaving two gaps. The gaps divide the circle into two pieces and one can count graphs by counting the gaps, and which side of each piece $z$ descend to. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) In the original fan graph, one gap in the wheel version is demanded. So you only get to choose the other gap and which sides of the pieces you descend from $z$ to. In this calculation there are only three cases instead of the four I list in the post: (1) $z$ is an endpoint. (2) the two gaps are adjacent (one of the two pieces is only a single vertex, so there is no choice which side of it you descend to). (3) The two gaps are not adjacent (two choices of descent side for each piece). With the fixed gap for the fan graph, these give $[2] + [2(2)] + [4(n-1)] = 4n+2$.